# PHP Post Working with Fields

Tags: php

I have a very simple form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<form method="post" action="">
<label>Filter By Zip Code:
<input maxlength="5" name="zipcode" size="6" type="text" /></label>
<label>Filter By Products:
 <select name="products">
  <option value="">Select Product</option>
  <option value="jewelry">Jewelry</option>
  <option value="homedecor">Home Decor</option>
  <option value="kitchen">Kitchen</option>
</select> </label>
    <label>Filter By Materials:
 <select name="materials">
  <option value="">Select Material</option>
  <option value="abs">ABS</option>
  <option value="gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="silver">Silver</option>
</select> </label>
<br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input name="clear" type="submit" value="Clear" />
</form>
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo "Nothing Selected";
}
elseif(isset($_POST['zipcode']) && ($_POST['zipcode'] != "")) {
$zip = $_POST['zipcode'];
        echo "Zip data " . $zip;
}

elseif(isset($_POST['products'])  && ($_POST['products'] != "")) {
$products = $_POST['products'];
        echo "Products data " . $products;
}
elseif(isset($_POST['materials'])   && ($_POST['materials'] != "")) {
$materials = $_POST['materials'];
        echo "Materials data " . $materials;
}
?>
```

When I am posting data It will only take the value of the first item selected.

I have tried breaking up the if ... elseif and doing some really redundant statements.

ie:

```
elseif(isset($_POST['materials']) && ($_POST['materials'] != "") || ($_POST['products'])  && ($_POST['products'] != "") || $_POST['zipcode'])  && ($_POST['zipcode'] != "")) {
```

That seems really to complicated and i cannot believe there is not an easier way.

I have tried using a switch ... case however get the same results.

What im looking for is what if two filters are selected?

What if all three are selected?

How can I get the data to post out correctly.

Comment: As your code is, the user cannot select multiple filters. Did you mean to use select multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking if "zipcode" is posted, and **if it's not**, if "products" is posted, etc...

You should change your "else if"s to "if" :

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "Nothing Selected";
}
else
{
    if(isset($_POST['zipcode']) && ($_POST['zipcode'] != ""))
    {
        $zip = $_POST['zipcode'];
       echo "Zip data " . $zip;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['products']) && ($_POST['products'] != ""))
    {
        $products = $_POST['products'];
        echo "Products data " . $products;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['materials']) && ($_POST['materials'] != ""))
    {
        $materials = $_POST['materials'];
       echo "Materials data " . $materials;
    }
}
?>
```

By the way, you could use "if (!empty($_POST['myfield']))" instead of checking "isset" and then egal to empty.

Another thing : inputs are not supposed to be inside the label, so you should have :

```
<label for="myfield">My field :</label>
<input name="myfield" ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo "Nothing Selected";
}
else {
        if(isset($_POST['zipcode']) && ($_POST['zipcode'] != "")) {
          $zip = $_POST['zipcode'];
          echo "Zip data " . $zip;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['products'])  && ($_POST['products'] != "")) {
          $products = $_POST['products'];
          echo "Products data " . $products;
        }
        if(isset($_POST['materials'])   && ($_POST['materials'] != "")) {
          $materials = $_POST['materials'];
          echo "Materials data " . $materials;
        }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Be aware that depending on what you plan to do with this data, it might be a big security leach... Be carefull if you plan on inserting this in a database. You might in that case want to read about SQL injections.

Comment: You should also use empty() to check if the posted value is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

You simply shouldn't use elseif's as it will only pass in one of those statements, the first actually as you noticed. Use if's instead...

Edit : see naincy gupta's answer which shows exactly what I meant :-)